# Swapping values within two pinned boxes

Tags: rust

Suppose I have two `Pin<T>`s, e.g. I got them from `Box::pin(struct_of_type_T)`, a `Box` owns the pointer to the underlying value of type T, a `Pin` ensures that the value (of type `T`) to which the pointer is pointing to is never moved.

Can I swap the two pointers within the 'Pinned-box'?

```
 pinned_box_1                   pinned_box_2
|-------------|                |-------------|
| pointer_one |<--swap them--?>| pointer_two |
|-------------|                |-------------|
       |                              |
       V                              V
 struct_of_type_T_one          struct_of_type_T_two
|-------------|                |-------------|
|  value_one  |                | value_two   |
|-------------|                |-------------|
 fixed_addr                     fixed_addr
```

If yes, how do I swap them? `std::mem::swap` will work in this case?

Comment: Is the type `Unpin` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you don't even need `std::mem::swap`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut pointer_one = Box::pin(99);
    let mut pointer_two = Box::pin(88);
    
    println!("pointer_one: {:p}, {}", pointer_one, *pointer_one);
    println!("pointer_two: {:p}, {}", pointer_two, *pointer_two);
    
    std::mem::swap(&mut pointer_one, &mut pointer_two);
    // (pointer_one, pointer_two) = (pointer_two, pointer_one); //also works
    
    println!("pointer_one: {:p}, {}", pointer_one, *pointer_one);
    println!("pointer_two: {:p}, {}", pointer_two, *pointer_two);
}
```

output:

```
pointer_one: 0x558a90ebb9d0, 99
pointer_two: 0x558a90ebb9f0, 88
pointer_one: 0x558a90ebb9f0, 88
pointer_two: 0x558a90ebb9d0, 99
```

Note: this is the answer to the question in the body, the answer to the title is no, it's not possible, that's exactly what `Pin` was made to prevent, the moving of the values.